# UnknownHostException and /etc/hosts

Tags: java, linux, host, hosts, jedis

I have records in /etc/hosts file which contains IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for `host-name.com`
But I sometimes get `UnknownHostException` like:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: host-name.com 
  at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:137) 
  at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:65) 
  at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1706) 
  at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:28) 
  at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188) 
  at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:38) 
    ... 2 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host-name.com 
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178) 
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) 
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) 
  at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:132) 
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

How it's possible and how can I solve it?

- Linux 3.2 (Debian stable) with unscd
- java 1.7.0_45 with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- /etc/nsswitch.conf has line `hosts:          files dns`
- /etc/hosts permissions `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: "sometimes" : does it mean that it does work sometimes, but not at other times with the same hostname?

Comment: yes, it mostly works (something like 99% of cases), but sometimes fail with same hostname

Comment: Try disconnecting your computer from the network and seeing if you get an `UnknownHostException` then.

Comment: When computer is disconnected i'm getting `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Okay, dunno why this question is closed, BUT I had exactly the same case and the answer is: your file descriptor limit is exceeded (or almost exceeded). System fails to read the hosts file since it needs a free file descriptor to open it. Unfortunately, the UnknownHostException exception is misleading. When I replaced hostname with an IP address, I started to get "Too many open files".

Comment: @Deinlandel Thank you, you are likely correct. I had problem with file descriptors limit at same time and was not able to connect two events.